# Use ordered query results in another query without separate processing?

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikidata

How can i access predicate + object pairs from a sorted result list for a new query by their line number?

Example query from Wikidata:

```
SELECT ?p ?o (COUNT (?o) as ?oCount) WHERE{
  ?s ?p ?o.                 #return every predicate + object...
  ?s wdt:P31 wd:Q5.         #...for humans
  ?s wdt:P19 wd:Q37100.     #...born in Auckland (NZL)
  ?s wdt:P21 wd:Q6581097.   #...which are male
}
GROUP BY ?p ?o ?oCount
ORDER BY DESC(?oCount)      #order by most common predicate/object combination
```

[Link to this query.](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%28COUNT%20%28%3Fo%29%20as%20%3FoCount%29%20WHERE%7B%0A%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo.%09%09%09%09%09%23return%20every%20predicate%20%2B%20object...%0A%20%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%09%09%09%23...for%20humans%0A%20%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP19%20wd%3AQ37100.%09%09%23...born%20in%20Auckland%20%28NZL%29%0A%20%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP21%20wd%3AQ6581097.%09%23...which%20are%20male%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%3FoCount%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3FoCount%29%09%09%23order%20by%20most%20common%20predicate%2Fobject%20combination)

These are some of the first results (edited for more clarity):

```
p                           o                                 oCount
--------------------------------------------------------------------
wdt:P19 (place of birth)    wd:Q37100 (Auckland)              1083
wdt:P21 (gender)            wd:Q6581097 (male)                1083
wdt:P31 (instance of)       wd:Q5 (human)                     1083
wdt:P27 (country)           wd:Q664 (New Zealand)             844
(...)
wdt:P106 (occupation)       wd:Q14373094 (rugby player)       202
(...)
wdt:P69 (educated at)       wd:Q492467 (Univ. of Auckland)    62
```

Now i want to do the following query:
**Return all subjects with the nth predicate + object of this result list.**

My actual use case is combining multiple rows of these reults with 'AND' or 'OR', e.g. return all subjects where the first 5 predicates+objects of this results are given.

Knowing how to access certain rows from the results would be a good start. I don't want to use a separate query by reading the results (with a script) and using them as input for a second query, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Knowing how to access certain rows from the results would be a good start. I don't want to use a separate query by reading the results (with a script) and using them as input for a second query, if possible.

That's not really possible.  You can use **order by** in a subquery, but the results aren't available in the outer query as an ordered list of results; they're just provided to the outer query.  However, if you really want just the *n<sup>th</sup>* result, you can also use **limit** and **offset**, and that may be sufficient.  For instance, you'd do something like the following (deliberately simplifying for the sake of example, and including sample data for completeness):

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:p :hasRank 1 .
:q :hasRank 2 .
:r :hasRank 3 .
:s :hasRank 4 .
:t :hasRank 5 .
:u :hasRank 6 .
:v :hasRank 7 .
:x :hasRank 8 .

:a :s :s0, :s1, :s2 ;
   :t :t0, :t1 ;
   :u :u0, :u1, :u2, :u3 .
```

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?s ?p ?o {
  #-- find the fifth ?p by rank
  { select ?p {
      ?p :hasRank ?rank
    }
    order by ?rank
    limit 1
    offset 4
  }

  #-- get triples using ?p
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

```
-----------------
| s  | p  | o   |
=================
| :a | :t | :t1 |
| :a | :t | :t0 |
-----------------
```

Comment: Unfortunately, just accessing the first n results doesn't fit my problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @rinderwahn You said "Now i want to do the following query:
Return all subjects with the nth predicate + object of this result list." The code here is simplified.  If you use OFFSET along with LIMIT, you can get exactly the nth result. I just updated the answer to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was about to edit my comment. Using OFFSET should do the job. I'm really new to SPARQL.

Comment: @rinderwahn I just updated the answer again with a complete example.  Does this work for your case?